# Checking for CMake Variables

Tags: cmake

I have the following CMake code snippet in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8 FATAL_ERROR)

message(STATUS "Before setting - ${MY_VARIABLE}")

# first check
if(NOT DEFINED ${MY_VARIABLE})
  set(MY_VARIABLE true)
endif(NOT DEFINED ${MY_VARIABLE})

message(STATUS "After setting - ${MY_VARIABLE}")

# second check
if(NOT DEFINED ${MY_VARIABLE})
  message(STATUS "What - ${MY_VARIABLE}")
endif(NOT DEFINED ${MY_VARIABLE})
```

The output from CMake configuration is:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Before setting - 
-- After setting - true
-- What - true
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/build
```

**Question**:
Why does the second check for variable definition report the variable is not defined even though it is defined? Surprisingly, the value of the variable is also printed correctly!

Comment: I don't think `if (NOT <var>)` is true if the variable is not defined. I added it before my first check in the code snippet above, and it does not enter the true block.

CMake documentation says:
True if the constant is 1, ON, YES, TRUE, Y, or a non-zero number. False if the constant is 0, OFF, NO, FALSE, N, IGNORE, NOTFOUND, the empty string, or ends in the suffix -NOTFOUND. It does not talk about variable not being defined.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

There is a difference between: `if(NOT DEFINED VAR_NAME)` and `if(NOT DEFINED ${VAR_NAME})`

The first one refers to the variable and the other to its content.